# Can I exchange filenames in GIT?

Tags: git

If I have two files in my working directory,

ex) file1.txt file2.txt

and they are already on my GIT repository,

can I 'exchange' their name such that the content and version history of file1.txt goes to file2.txt and the other way around?

Comment: yes, you can either swap the file names or copy and paste the content without issue

Comment: Just rename and commit. Did you try this?

Comment: @joshmeranda Thanks! Git is way smarter than I thought.

Comment: @DonBranson I just did! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No. You can "exchange" their names but content and version history would remain same. So if `file1` had "abc" text and `file2` had "pqr" and you exchange their names, then `file1` would have `pqr` and `file2` would have `abc`.